# How to do some arithmatic measurements in javascript loop

Tags: javascript

im just a beginner, I'm making a system with some inputs and determine the output to be 1 and 0, but before that i put these inputs in data array to do the math like index[0] - index[1]. while i fetch real time data.

the real time data would be in json, which is (first month)

```
data 1 :{ "name" : "grace", "score" : 87 }
```

(second month)

```
data 2 : { "name" : "grace" "score" : 77 }
```

at this point I would like to put score 87 to index[0] which is the first score she got and 77 to index[1] which is the nex score she get. then after the result I would convert it like `if(result<0){ status = 0; }` which mean her score is going down else `{ status = 1; }` which mean her score is increasing.

then i would store the result into mysql database.

and i did this code

```
var dat = []; var newDat = {}; if (m = firstMonth){ newDat[0] = score; var a = newDat[0]; } else if (m = secondMonth){ newDat[1] = score; var b = newDat[1]; }

var result = a-b; if(result<0){ result = 0; } else { result = 1 } console.log(result);
```

but I only recieve result 1 which is not the right answer.

or can I input the data to an array with loop while the program calculate the result?
help me to solve the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Since 87-77 = 10, which means result = 10.
So obviously it will always execute the else statement. And will do result = 1.

Comment: yes, i mean i got the same answer for the other scores. is that because the value in the array doesnt change regarding the incoming input or is there something not right with the code?

Comment: Can you list other scores?